# iOS app launch image not change when I update app from store

Tags: ios, upgrade, launch

I used Launch Screen for my app v1.0.1 .and I updated My app to v1.0.2 that the launch Image is using Launch Images Source in Assets . when I launch the app but I get the launch image of old version Launch Screen ,not the new assets. Delete and reinstall works fine, but updating from app store show the weird things. Does anyone know the issue and have a solution ?

Comment: Have you cleaned the project?

Comment: @Horst I submitted it to app store，if the project is not cleaned ,the first time who install app should be the launch screen of v1.0.1. but actually turns to be v1.0.2's launch image